# Ionic Modal with ngMap using Google Place Autocomplete Won't Select Prediction

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ng-map

I'm using [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/) with Ionic 1.2.x and I've put together custom-control that contains a places autocomplete directive that in a plain HTML test works, but when I put it inside the ionic application and open it in a modal the on-place-changed event never triggers when clicking on the places autocomplete prediction.  When I mouse over the list of place predictions the mouse cursor icon doesn't change seemingly indicating the elements are not available for clicking.

**UPDATE**

I found a reference to this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1798), but the solutions don't appear to work when in a modal according to the last couple posts where `data-tap-disabled="true"` is used on `pac-container`.

I've attached an abridge [CodePen of the issue](http://codepen.io/mtpultz/pen/PNyMKv?editors=0010).  It's really easy to replicate.

**DIRECTIVE**

```
<ng-map id="gmap">

    // ...

    <custom-control class="gmap-place-autocomplete-control-container"
                    position="TOP_CENTER">

            <input placeholder="Search for places"
                   types="{{ createEventCtrl.types }}"
                   ng-model="createEventCtrl.address"
                   on-place-changed="createEventCtrl.placeChanged()"
                   places-auto-complete>

    </custom-control>

    // ...

</ng-map>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working using this [fix](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-places-not-working-in-ionic-modal-window/35374/12), but we don't like using jQuery in our AngularJS applications so I changed it a bit to be within the AngularJS API with a bit of native JavaScript.

**Markup**

```
<input placeholder="Search for places" 
       ng-model="locationCtrl.event.location"
       on-place-changed="locationCtrl.placeChanged()"
       places-auto-complete
       ng-focus="locationCtrl.disableTap($event)">
```

**Controller**

```
vm.disableTap = function(event) {

    var input = event.target;

    // Get the predictions element
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
    container = angular.element(container);

    // Apply css to ensure the container overlays the other elements, and
    // events occur on the element not behind it
    container.css('z-index', '5000');
    container.css('pointer-events', 'auto');

    // Disable ionic data tap
    container.attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');

    // Leave the input field if a prediction is chosen
    container.on('click', function(){
        input.blur();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, i had the same issue and here is the solution i built :

I put this code into my ionic index.html :

```
<script>
 $(document).on({
     'DOMNodeInserted': function () {
         $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).attr("data-tap-disabled","true");
     }
 }, '.pac-container');
</script>
```

This will automaticaly disable TAP (the thing that makes the prediction selection impossible) anywhere you use google places autocomplete in your app.